# Сравнение разности дат Django ORM

Tags: orm, django

Здравствуйте!

Неоспоримое желание руководства использовать исключительно Django ORM обернулись для моего запроса, составленного за несколько десят минут, в целую эпопею.

В упрощенном виде запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT b.name,
    count(b.name),
    avg(c.rate1),
    ....
    avg(c.rate23)
FROM c

INNER JOIN a ON a.rates_id = c.id
INNER JOIN d ON d.id = a.request_id
INNER JOIN b ON b.id = d.some_id
INNER JOIN e ON e.id = d.lookup_id

LEFT JOIN ir ON ir.lookup_ptr_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN in ON in.lookup_ptr_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN n ON n.lookup_ptr_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN r ON r.lookup_ptr_id = e.id

WHERE (((ir.date_a - a.date) < '5 days') OR
       ((in.date_a - a.date) < '5 days') OR
       ((n.date_a - a.date) < '5 days') OR
       ((r.date_a - a.date) < '5 days'))
    AND e.date IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY b.id
```

Т.е. все очень просто, а вот с ORM - сложно, точнее сложна часть запроса `WHERE`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом в Django ORM воткнуть вот эту часть запроса:

```
WHERE (((ir.date_a - a.date) < '5 days') OR
       ((in.date_a - a.date) < '5 days') OR
       ((n.date_a - a.date) < '5 days') OR
       ((r.date_a - a.date) < '5 days'))
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Из [доки][1]

> Example:
> 
> Entry.objects.extra(where=["foo='a' OR
> bar = 'a'", "baz = 'a'"])
> ...translates (roughly) into the
> following SQL:
> 
> SELECT * FROM blog_entry WHERE
> (foo='a' OR bar='a') AND (baz='a')


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: Использовать не удастся пока не будут подключены таблицы `ir`, `in`, `n` и `r`. А они, как видно из полей выбора подключены не будут.

Answer (score 1):

Это должно решить вашу проблему - [Сложные запросы с помощью объектов Q](http://djbook.ru/rel1.4/topics/db/queries.html#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Вот бы еще пример, для случая 

    WHERE (ir.date_a - a.date) < '5 days'

Мне эта ссылка очень знакома, только примера там такого нет. Каким образом мне указать, что это должен быть именно знак "<"? Как мне указать постфикс "__day"?